# Toggle <spans> selectivly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a link whose title should change from "Add Comment" to "Edit Comment" only if a child  has a class of .has-comment. What complicates the matter is that I also toggle icons which are also in a .

So if the div.additional-comments has class of .has-comment then I'd like the  text to read "Edit Comment" otherwise it should read "Add Comment".

See working code here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgdaf5ar/2/)

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a class="toggle-comments">
                <span class="add-comment" style="display:none;">Add</span>
                <span class="edit-comment">Edit</span> Comments
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right" aria-hidden="true" style="display: inline-block;"></span>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></span>
            </a>
            <div class="additional-comments has-comment" style="display:none;">
                <textarea>Comment is here...</textarea>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a class="toggle-comments">
                <span class="add-comment">Add</span>
                <span class="edit-comment" style="display:none;">Edit</span> Comments
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-right" aria-hidden="true" style="display: inline-block;"></span>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"></span>
            </a>
            <div class="additional-comments" style="display:none;">
                <textarea></textarea>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Script

```
// Toggle Comments
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.toggle-comments').click(function() {
        $(this).next('.additional-comments').toggle("fast");
        $(this).find('span').fadeToggle(0);
    });
});
```

Comment: What was your question?

Comment: What exactly do you wish to achieve?

Comment: If the <div> has a class of .has-comment toggle the text to "Edit Comment", otherwise have it read "Add Comment".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure if I understand what you want to achieve so I updated your fiddle, tell me if its what you aimed : http://jsfiddle.net/benjaminb/mgdaf5ar/3/

I only changed this

```
$(this).find('span.glyphicon').fadeToggle(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore all your glyphicons by changing your `find` to:

```
$(this).find('span:not(.glyphicon)')
```

Comment: Guess I am not clear in my wording. If the div.additional-comments has class of .has-comment then I'd like the <a> text to read "Edit Comment" otherwise it should read "Add Comment".